# Version Compatibility Issues Solidity v0.4 to 0.5 | Identity Contracts ERC 725 | abi.encodePacked not working

Tags: solidity-0.5.x, erc725

This is in reference to ERC 725 Identity Contracts. I am updating the contract to version 0.5. The issue arise in a specific function where it requires a single argument to the call method which I have provided using **abi.encodePacked** but receiving the following error

**2 arguments given but expected 1**. This function requires a single bytes argument. If all your arguments are value types, you can use abi.encode(...) to properly generate it.

For reference, I have added the code snippets

```
 struct Execution {
        address to;
        uint256 value;
        bytes data;
        bool approved;
        bool executed;
    }
```

```
function approve(uint256 _id, bool _approve) public returns (bool success) {
        require(
            keyHasPurpose(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender)), 2),
            "Sender does not have action key"
        );

        emit Approved(_id, _approve);

        if (_approve == true) {
            executions[_id].approved = true;
            success = executions[_id].to.call(executions[_id].data, 0);
            if (success) {
                executions[_id].executed = true;
                emit Executed(
                    _id,
                    executions[_id].to,
                    executions[_id].value,
                    executions[_id].data
                );
                return;
            } else {
                emit ExecutionFailed(
                    _id,
                    executions[_id].to,
                    executions[_id].value,
                    executions[_id].data
                );
                return;
            }
        } else {
            executions[_id].approved = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Getting the following error on this line of code

**`success = executions[_id].to.call(executions[_id].data, 0);`**

> **TypeError:** Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1. This function requires a single bytes argument. If all your arguments are value types, you can use abi.encode(...) to properly generate it.

I have already tried the following solution

`success = executions[_id].to.call(abi.encodePacked(executions[_id].data, 0))`

But the issue still persists

Comment: Have you tried `abi.encode(executions[_id].data, 0)`?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried it like this  
`success = executions[_id].to.call(abi.encode(executions[_id].data,0));` <br/>


 but receives the following error  
 **Type tuple(bool,bytes memory) is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool**

Comment: @AdamBoudjemaa,  According to breaking changes [solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html) the `.call()` function only accepts a single **byte** argument which is not padded   
So `abi.encode()` will not be suitable here since it pads the arguments

Comment: @QasidLabeed Adam is right you have to use `abi.encode()` when calling another contract because you need to pad arguments. The new error is caused because call returns two values. You have to do something like `(bool success, bytes result) = <address>.call(abi.encode(<params>));`.

Comment: Thanks, Ismael, the issue is resolved.